# Создание *.exe с интерфейсом tkinter (библиотека pandastable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Тяжело сформулировать вопрос, но постараюсь. Хочу при запуске exe-шника выводить таблицу из SQL и выполнять различные манипуляции с помощью фильтров. Реализованный интерфейс подобного нашёл в библиотеке pandastable, получилось привязать свою таблицу SQL (в среде разработки все работает), но вот с реализацией exe возникла проблема. Пользуюсь Auto-py-to-exe, понимаю, что это надстройка pyinstaller, но с ним пока сложно разобраться. Кое-что пофиксил добавлением библиотек, пришлось даже переименовывать tkinter в Tkinter и доставать папку ttk из tk, так как программа не видит. Все это выглядит ужасно и очень костыльно, а под конец вообще вылезли ошибки такого рода:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\pandastable\core.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox, simpledialog
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tkinter import commondialog
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tkinter import Frame, _get_temp_root, _destroy_temp_root
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_temp_root' from 'tkinter' (C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkinter\__init__.pyc)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdtable1.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\pandastable\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\pandastable\core.py", line 31, in <module>
    import tkFileDialog as filedialog
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkFileDialog.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tkinter import commondialog
  File "C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tkinter import Frame, _get_temp_root, _destroy_temp_root
ImportError: cannot import name '_get_temp_root' from 'tkinter' (C:\prog\PolisInf\tableinf v0.1\pdtable1\tkinter\__init__.pyc)
```

Ну а вопрос в том как их решить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не были импортированы либы в стандартный питон, все дёргал из venv IDE, когда установил, все проблемы решились. Вручную даже если все библиотеки через добавление папок установить, все равно не находит какие-то файлы, следовательно не работает импорт.